# Why was the Spanish kingdom in America called New Spain if Spain didn't exist as a country back then?

Tags: colonial-america, spain, spanish-empire, mexico, new-world

When the conquistadores arrived in America, the territory of current Spain was divided into multiple crowns/kingdoms but it wasn't what we know today as Spain. I understand at that moment the territory was ruled by the crown of Castile and Aragon but still, each kingdom was working as an independent state.

So my question is why did Hernan Cortes name the territory in America "New Spain" if there wasn't an "Old Spain" to begin with?

Comment: Spain as the territory of the Iberian Peninsula was called Espanna/Spanya/Spania since the 12th century, as you can read in the Crónica de San Juan de la Peña and in the works of Bernat Desclot and Ramon Muntaner. And that without considering the Visigothis use of Hispania for the name of their domains.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786) What's wrong with the answer in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spain) (referenced above by C. Martin). This is an example of an interesting historical blind spot - modern national identities  obscure the complexity of pre-modern intermingling of ethnic, governmental and proto-state identities.  The terms we use today "Spain" can have quite different meanings as we go back in time.

Comment: @CarlosMartin, not to mention it *also* being the name of the Roman province, which is an important factor in nomenclature there. In fact, across Europe there’s several states that hark back to the names of Roman provinces in their names: not only Spain, but Britain and Italy as well. Not to mention (in many languages), the names of Syria, Egypt, Libya, and Palestine:

Comment: Was it a kingdom?  Spanish Wikipedia uses the term *virreinato*

Comment: [Related](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/63698/17887)

Comment: I feel the underlying misunderstanding here is that "regions of the world" and "government" (and, relatedly, nationality) were not always as tightly linked as they are now. Spain as a geographical region existed long before Spain as a national country.

Comment: @CarlosMartin So it wasn't until later that Portugal came to be considered to not be part of "Spain"?

Comment: @Accumulation Yes, the independence of Portugal is actually a fascinating subject. From the 9th to the early 12th centuries it was merely a county in the Kingdom of Leon. The first Portuguese king, Alfonso I, declared his independence after some decisive victories against the Muslims in the South of his new kingdom and reconquering a lot of territory. The common explanation is that the Portuguese didn't have much help from the rest of the Spanish kingdoms in these battles so a sort of nationalistic sentiment was born

Comment: @CarlosMartin In a sense, he declared independence after [defeating his mom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_São_Mamede) in battle in 1128.  Lisbon was [conquered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Lisbon) in 1147 with the help of English Crusaders.  In any case, only [around 1300](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denis_of_Portugal#Administration), was Portuguese considered an official language. During the succession crises around 1385 and 1580, much of the Portuguese Nobility sided with Castile. Nationalism was for the working people.

Comment: People spoke about Italy (Italia) and Germany (Germania) long before those regions became unified countries, just as we today can speak about e.g. Scandinavia despite it not being a single country...

Comment: @Julio Bastido  Cortez didn't name the Spanish territories in the New World "New Spain", he named some of them "New Spain", namely lands in Mexico.  Eventually The Viceroyalty of New Spain included Mexico, the US Southwest, Central America, and the Philippines.   The title of the Spanish monarch for all of the New World was "King of  the Indias, the Islands and Mainland in the Ocean Sea"..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

‘Spain’ in the sense of ‘Hispania’, alluding to the Roman province, certainly existed as a concept at the time, even if the Kingdom didn’t (yet). Indeed, there’s several medieval Kings in the Iberian peninsula who used the title ‘[Imperator totius Hispaniae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperator_totius_Hispaniae)’ (ie, ‘Emperor of all Spain’).

See, for example, the epitaph of Ferdinand I of Leon, who died in 1103:

> H. E. TUMULATUS FERNANDUS MAGNUS **REX TOTIUS HISPANIAE**. FILIUS SANCTII REGIS PIRENAEORUM ET TOLOSAE. ISTA TRANSTULIT CORPORA. SANCTORUM IN LEGIONE BEATI ISIDORI ARCHIEPISCOPI AB HISPALI VICENTIIMARTYRIS AB ABELA. ET FECIT ECCLESIAM HANC LAPIDEAM. QUAE OLIM FUERAT LUTEA, HIC PRAELIANDO **FECIT SIBI TRIBUTARIOS OMNES SARRACENOS HISPANIAE** ET CEPIT COLIMBRIAM, LAMEGO, VESEO, ET ALIAS. ISTE VI CEPIT REGNA GARSIAE ET VEREMUDI. OBIIT VI K. JANUARII. ERA MCIII.

Translated:

> *Here is buried Ferdinand the Great, **king of all Spain**, son of Sancho king of the Pyrenees and Toulouse. He transferred to León the holy bodies of Saint Isidore archbishop, from Seville, and of Vicente martyr, from Avila, and built this church of stone, which in another time was of mud. **He made his tributaries**, with arms, **all the Saracens of Spain**. He seized Coimbra, Lamego, Viseo and other places. He took by force the kingdoms of Garcia and Vermudo. He died on December 27, (the year) 1103.*

Another example, Ferdinand III of Castile, who died in 1292 and is buried in Seville's Cathedral; note how "ESPAÑA" is already written  in its modern form, not in Latin:

[image]

> *AQVI YAZE EL MVY ONDRADO HERNANDO, SEÑOR DE CASTIELLA E DE TOLEDO, E DE LEON, E DE GALICIA, DE SEVILLA, DE CORDOVA, DE MVRCIA, DE IHAEN, **EL QVE CONQVISSO TODA ESPAÑA**, EL MAS LEAL, EL MAS VERDADERO, EL MAS FRANCO, EL MAS ESFORZADO, EL MAS APVESTO, EL MAS GRANADO, EL MAS ZOFRIDO, EL MAS HOMILDOSO, EL QVE MAS TEMIE A DIOS, EL QVE MAS LE FACIE SERVICIO, EL QVE QVEBRANTO E DESTRVYO A TODOS SVS ENEMIGOS, EL QVE ALZO, E ONDRO TODOS SVS AMIGOS, **E CONQVISSO LA CIVDAD DE SEVILLA, QVE ES CABEZA DE TODA ESPAÑA**, E PASSO EN EL POSTRIMERO DIA DE MAYO, EN LA ERA DE MIL E CC. E NOVAENTA*

Translated:

> Here lies the most noble Ferdinand, lord of Castile and of Toledo, and of Leon, and of Galicia, of Seville, of Cordoba, of Murcia, of Jaen, **the one who conquered all Spain**, the most loyal, the most true, the most frank, the most hardworking, the most handsome, the most distinguished, the most suffered, the most humble, the one who feared God most, who did Him most service, who broke and destroyed all his enemies, who raised up, and honored all his friends, and **conquered the city of Seville, which is the head of all Spain**, and passed on the last day of May, in the year of one thousand and two hundred and ninety.

So Spain being a concept in the 1500s shouldn’t be all that surprising.

In exactly the same way ‘Britain’ (ie, Britannia), and ‘Italy’ were also concepts, even though a Kingdom of Great Britain wouldn’t exist until 1707, and a unified Kingdom of Italy encompassing the entire peninsula wouldn’t exist until 1861/70.

Comment: "[A] unified Kingdom of Italy encompassing the entire peninsula wouldn’t exist until 1861/70." -- that is not exactly true. The Ostrogothic Kingdom was called *Regnum Italiae*, and it included the whole peninsula.

Comment: @Riwen there also were the medieval kingdom of Italy (later part of the HRE, then defunct) and the Napoleonic kingdom of Italy, even though neither controlled the entire peninsula. The related concept did definitely exist. Similarly, the medieval kingdom of Germany, which just got subsumed into the HRE.

Comment: Would Emperor Charles V (for whom Cortes was working) have been styled "King of Spain" at the time, or would he have been known to his contemporaries as King of Castile and King of Aragon distinctly?  (His Wikipedia page styles him as "King of Spain", but I can't tell if that's an anachronism.) -- I think implicit in the question is why Cortes chose "New Spain" rather than, e.g.,  "New Castile".

Comment: @R.M. Charles I in Spain

Comment: @R.M. exactly my point, does it mean people back then where referring themselves as Spanish already?

Comment: @JulioBastida they called themselves castellanos, gallegos, etc. But during the 13th-15th centuries, both Castille and Aragon annexed several other kingdoms and, for example, the King of Castille was automatically the King of Leon, the King of Navarre, the King of Galicia and several other kingdoms that had to share a king. With the marriage of the Catholic Monarchs in 1469, the kingdoms of Castille and Aragon got joined under the name of Kings of Spain. Only on paper: their grandson, Carlos I (V for most of the world) had to be recognized as King of Castille and after that, King of Aragon.

Comment: @CarlosMartin Until the first Bourbon dissolved the Cortes de Aragón, centralized everything (like in France) and created the red-yellow flag inspired by the Aragonese Senyera to compensate the Crown of Aragón for its loss of power.

Comment: @R.M.; the title ‘King/Queen of Spain’ wasn’t formally used until the reign of Isabel II; although Joseph Bonaparte had, briefly, used the title. Until then, the titles used were ‘King/Queen of Castile, Aragon…’, etc.

Comment: r.e.: Britain/Britannia, my understanding is that is the name of the *island*, currently containing the countries of England, Scotland, and Wales, which along with Northern Ireland and a few smaller islands form the UK, etc.  But the name "Britain" is geographical, not political.  The equivalent for Spain might be Iberia (though that also includes Portugal).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You might find [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Iberia%2CHispania&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) interesting

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Not sure how - Google ngrams simply represent *usage* over time, but not the official terminology.  Just as many citizens of the UK might refer to themselves as "British" rather than "English", "Scottish", or "Welsh".  Or those in the US call themselves "Americans" despite that being 2 whole continents and not just one country.  It is interesting though that there does seem to be a small spike in "Iberia" at the 1500-end of the chart - shame the data doesn't go back any earlier...  "Iberia" definitely dominates most of the timeline if you change the corpus to Spanish though.

Comment: @user22453 King Ferdinand I of Leon died in Anno Domini 1065, not 1103. 38 years later.  HIs tomb gives his death year in the era of Spain or Era of the Caesars, counting the years from 38 BC.  His son Alfonso VI was actually the monarch in 1103. The tomb of Ferdinand  III says 1290 not 1292, and he actually died in AD 1252.